# RuntimeError: Conflicting 'product_product_options' models in application 'catalogue': on Oscar 2

Tags: django-oscar

I am using Django==2.2.6 And django-oscar==2.0.2.
Trying to custom the Oscar models but every its not working...

The error is ..

```
File "/home/dipto/env/oscar/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 316, in __new__
    new_class._meta.apps.register_model(new_class._meta.app_label, new_class)
  File "/home/dipto/env/oscar/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 229, in register_model
    (model_name, app_label, app_models[model_name], model))
RuntimeError: Conflicting 'product_product_options' models in application 'catalogue': <class 'oscar.apps.catalogue.models.Product_product_options'> and <class 'catalogue.models.Product_product_options'>.
```

Following this....

- Created a App with the name of "catalogue"
- Added it as Django app to INSTALLED_APPS
- Added a models.py and admin.py

In catalogue app models.py

```
from django.db import models
from oscar.apps.catalogue.abstract_models import AbstractProduct

class Product(AbstractProduct):
    Test_URL = models.URLField()

from oscar.apps.catalogue.models import *
```

In catalogue app **init**.py

```
default_app_config = 'catalogue.apps.CatalogueConfig'
```

In catalogue app apps.py

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class CatalogueConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'catalogue'
    label= 'shop mane'
```

Comment: Did you scan your code on "product_product_options" and found multiple entries? Please provide a minimal code example of your problem.

Comment: Please read the [documentation for how to fork an Oscar app](https://django-oscar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/fork_app.html). You can't add a second `catalogue` app to your `INSTALLED_APPS` - you instead have to replace the core `catalogue` app.